# Can FFMPEG or any other project detect an audio file contains only noises?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, noise

I have a batch of audio files which recording people's voice. But some of this audio files record only noises or microphone burst. I want to detect these files and jump over them while processing my program.

I'm not sure whether ffmpeg can do this. If yes, could you guys provide me a link of that method? If not, do you know if there is some other software can do this? Or do you have any solution or suggestion to this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by looking at peak values and duration. [SOX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features) is a program that allows shell scripting which could batch analyze this. There is a large user base and forum as well.

[Here](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=83319) is a link to a forum topic discussing it's use on batch discovering peak values and outputting information to a .csv file.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But how do people's voice differ from noise in term of peak value and duration? Like noise has only a short and low peak?

Comment: I missed this reply. My apologies.  You should define noise. General noise is wideband while interference occurs in band. AS I stated before you should look for peak values.